# publishing data one after the other with constant time

Tags: ros, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to publish  data from the XML file using pugixml.I need to make the publication (content) one by one with constant time.For example after the publication of first data,it has to wait for 10 secs and then the second data should follow.
Since i m in the beginner level in ROS,i don't know how to achieve this task?

Can anyone suggest an idea?

Thanks,

Best Regards,
Annaiyan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207891/publishing-data-one-after-the-other-with-constant-time/) by [run_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/22274/run_vision/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should look at [ROS Timers Overview](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Timers) and a [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/Timers).

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2015-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0